# How to serve static files using Spock and Lucid?

Tags: haskell, haskell-spock, haskell-lucid

Getting started with web development using Haskell, Spock, and Lucid, I can't figure out how to serve my static files. In the directory of `Main.hs` I have `/static/css/main.css`, which contains just a background colour to see if the css is indeed applied. So my directory tree looks like

```
app
├── Main.hs
└── static
    └── css
        └── main.css
```

However, with the below configuration, the `main.css` file is not found (it contains a 404 when inspecting it with Firefox). Other than that, the site shows fine.

I have tried to mimick the [funblog](https://github.com/agrafix/funblog) example when it comes to serving these files (with Wai), altered for Lucid instead of Blaze. In particular the `middleware $ staticPolicy (addBase "static")` from [`Web/Blog.hs`](https://github.com/agrafix/funblog/blob/65c2b41019ae3a3bd04a2ffb92e028f167295c7d/src/Web/Blog.hs#L87) and the line where we link the css from [`Web/Views/Site.hs`](https://github.com/agrafix/funblog/blob/65c2b41019ae3a3bd04a2ffb92e028f167295c7d/src/Web/Views/Site.hs#L28).

```
module Main where    

import           Network.Wai.Middleware.Static
import           Lucid
import           Web.Spock
import           Web.Spock.Config
import           Web.Spock.Lucid         (lucid)

type Server a = SpockM () () () a

main :: IO ()
main = do
  cfg <- defaultSpockCfg () PCNoDatabase ()
  runSpock 8080 (spock cfg app)

app :: Server ()
app = do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (addBase "static")
  get root $ do
    lucid $ do
        head_ $ link_ [ rel_ "stylesheet"
                      , type_ "text/css"
                      , href_ "/css/main.css" 
                      ]
        body_ $ h1_ "Hello."
```

---

**Edit/Addition** Translating the Lucid to Blaze gives the same result (translation as below), so I must be missing something somewhere else.

```
-- Additional imports
import           Text.Blaze.XHtml5             ((!))
import qualified Text.Blaze.XHtml5             as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.XHtml5.Attributes  as A
import           Control.Monad.Trans           (MonadIO)
import           Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Utf8 (renderHtml)

-- The main function did not change. 

blaze :: MonadIO m => H.Html -> ActionCtxT ctx m a
blaze = lazyBytes . renderHtml

app :: Server ()
app = do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (addBase "static")
  get root $
    blaze $ do 
      H.head $
        H.link ! A.href "/css/main.css" ! A.rel "stylesheet"
      H.body $
        H.h1 "Hello Blaze."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `static` folder is in the root directory of your **project**, and not of your main file, i.e., the `static` folder should live next to (and not in) your `app` and/or `src` folder.

In this case that would be

```
├── app
│   └── Main.hs
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
```